# mvc api routing with variable to save basic path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am working in a mvc Api project and while routing actions using [route("api/MyCont/getspecific")] I realized that
 it would be a good idea to use a variable to store the basic path of this controller:"api/myCont", so I could reuse that part of the route and also make the maitenance of the code easier.

This is what I tried:

```
 public class MyContController : ApiController
{

    private readonly string BaseRoute="api/MyCont" ;

    [HttpGet]
    [Route(BaseRoute+"/GetSpecific")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSpecificItem( string ItemId)
    {
    /* do something
     get the item from a source
    */

      return Ok(Item);
    }

}
```

but when I do it, there is an error in the route "an object reference is required for the non static field, method or roperty BaseRoute".

What should I do to fix it? 
Do you think is a good idea what I am doing, in terms of good practices?

Comment: It need to be `const` (not `readonly`)

Comment: Note the normal way is to use `[RoutePrefix("api/MyCont")]` on the controller. Refer [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code, the varible which you use it should be static becuase while registering Rout in rout table the expression should be evaludated.

```
        private const string BaseRoute = "api/MyCont";
        [HttpGet]
        [Route(BaseRoute + "/GetSpecific")]
        public string Helloworld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
```